# How do text sizes compare between iPhone X, 8/Plus and SE?

Tags: iphone, font, resolution, text, accessibility

When considering a switch from one iPhone form factor to another, one of 
the importand aspect is:

**How physical text size compares between old and new phone (each of 
iPhone X, 8/Plus and SE)? How does different DPI affect it, if at all? And how much does the [Zoomed View](https://help.apple.com/iphone/10/#/iphd6804774e) setting change the size?**

This is especially important for elder and weak-eyesight users.

---

With release of iPhone X, my [earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147244/how-font-sizes-at-iphone-6-6-compare-to-earlier-iphones) becomes critically outdated, so I decided to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

### Identical between pre-X devices; +17% with Zoomed-View; +7% on X

On **SE**, **8** and **8 Plus** (and older devices of same form factor) text size is the same between devices, larger screen fits proportionally more text.

Zoomed View gives exactly the smaller-device amount of text in proportionally larger text size. **8 Plus** screen is 17% larger than **8**'s, and **SE** is 17% larger than **8** (measured by screen height / width).

Conversely, on **X** the text is size in the middle of Standard-View and Zoomed-View of earlier devices, roughly:

- 7% larger than on **8** (proportional to how **X** screen is wider than **8**)
- 9.5% smaller than on **8 Plus** in Zoomed-View (proportional to how **8 Plus** screen is wider than **X**)

DPI has no effect to text size on the apps I tried, no matter whether or not they support DynamicType system setting.

---

**Notes:**

- %% diffs are between width of equal text in equal apps, with identical settings
- screen width diffs are based on official specs: screen size in pixels divided by PPI
- measured and researched on my own; I would appreciate link to an authoritative source or suggestions on better metrics